# Postgresql mode INFORMIX or INFORMIX_SE

Tags: postgresql, compatibility, informix, ecpg

In `PostgreSQL`, with `ecpg`, there are two compatibility modes: `INFORMIX`, `INFORMIX_SE`.

Is there a difference between `INFORMIX` setting mode and `INFORMIX_SE` setting mode? I do not see any detail about this [Postgresql Doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ecpg-informix-compat.html)

Thanks.

Comment: Good question. Take a look at `git grep --color -A 5 -B 5 INFORMIX_SE` in the sources. It looks like it affects `WITH HOLD` cursors and an error handling case. I haven't read into the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INFORMIX refers to Informix Dynamic Server and INFORMIX_SE refers to Informix Standard Engine. So you must know what type of Informix DB your target is. SE uses C-ISAM, where INFORMIX uses RSAM. Visit the [IBM Informix](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/informix/)  website for more info. This [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.gen_busug.doc%2Fc_fgl_odiagpgs_011.htm) also explains adaptability of PostgreSQL with both Informix DB models.

Comment: Thanks, the INFORMIX version I use is 7.24C9. Apparently, It should be a C-ISAM version : [see doc](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycleapp/PLCDetail.wss?synkey=A465583Y71672Y52&from=spf). Am I alright ?

Comment: Hmm, no upvote for the answer? Correct, you're using SE. Is it running on a Solaris 8 system?

Comment: I cannot upvote (I need 15 reputation). No we are running on RHEL 5.2